# Recover From Crashed Session

Tags: 12.10, command-line

Occasionally, my laptop dumps me out to a blank screen with an 'hid' error, indicating a problem with the mouse driver.

Short of actually fixing the underlying cause, which I have tried to do, how can I recover from this, and get back to, or start a new GUI session?

I know I can hit CTRL-ALT-F1 and get to a terminal prompt and log in.   But what do I do from there?  I tried entering **init 3**, and then **init 5**, but that doesn't get me to a login screen.

I hate rebooting and losing everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restart the X session, it's as simple as running:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

It's slightly odd that it's not doing that for you. It certainly used to but I guess the transition to lightdm and upstart have left it a little less bullet-proof than before.

If that moans about not being able to find a running job, just run `sudo start lightdm` instead.

---

To be clear, once X dies, you lose everything from your graphical session. Restarting it won't magically restore all the applications that were running, in the same state.

Comment: As Oli says, once X Crashes then all GUI programs in it die too(just like closing a Terminal that you have a program running in). All restarting X from the terminal will do is save you from having to wait through a Reboot.